# multiple networks between computers

Tags: samba

I have a Windows 7 laptop. And I having an Ubuntu machine that setup as a Samba server to hold my files I would like to have both computers accessible by Wi-Fi to the Internet but  to hold my files I would like to have both computers accessible by Wi-Fi to the Internet but  I want separate hard wired network between the machines.

I have a Linksys WRT54g Wi-Fi router that loses the Internet connection when I try to link the two computers together via wi-fi for file transfers. So I thought maybe I could ad-hoc network just the samba connection so it doesn't send any data via wi-fi. I figure it would make transfers quicker considering it's hard wire. Is it do-able?